# how to fit curve with two exponential terms in R

Tags: r, exponential

the formula is

```
f=exp(-d*t)+exp(g*t)-1
```

my dataset includes many observations(f in the formula) on several different times(t) for several subjects. And I want to get estimations on d and g.

How should I code for this in R? And I don't know how to determine starting values, since every subject might have different curve shapes.

Here are some hypothetical examples:

```
 subject         t       f
 1     1         0   515.6 
 2     1        70    62.9
 3     1       126    34.8
 4     1       181    18.5
 5     1       245    28.9
 6     1       289    29.6
 7     1       359   109.1
 8     1       408    33.2
 9     1       531    16.9
10     1       569    97.2
```

I have hundreds of subjects, and I want to estimate the parameters (d and g) on personal level, means different curve for different subject.

Comment: What do you mean  by starting values?

Comment: I look at some R functions for nonlinear curve fitting, they require a "start value" for the parameter estimates in the formula. See "start" in the "nls" function.

Comment: If d and g are both positive, you could assume the first term to be zero and solve for g as `ln(1+f)/t`. Using that, eliminate g and solve for d. If it's still not precise, you can use these as starting values for the non llinear solver.

Comment: I tried your way of estimating the start value, the first step is good. But the second parameter estimate is too small and not significant. I guess it is because the curve shapes are quite fluctuating and my formula is only a roughly fit.

Comment: Also, they're situations that only one exponential term is needed in some subjects. Since some subjects' curves are generally decreasing, or generally increasing. I found it hard to determine since I cannot examine every subject and decide a suitable curve formula for each one.

Comment: I would suggest asking a question on [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) about the right family of curves to fit.

Comment: Please share some example data. Do you want separate models for the subjects or a non-linear mixed effects model? Are you sure you want this model and not the full biexponential model for which R has a selfstarting model (`help("SSbiexp")`)?

Comment: actually this is a famous model describing tumor growth and inhibition, I guess my model choices are limited. the problem is, e.g., some patients only experience tumor growth, so their model only need one exponential term. I find it hard to let R decide for me whether 1 or 2 terms are needed.

Comment: Well, try the biexponential model. It could tell you (by fitting `A1` or `A2` to zero. (Obviously, you'd need to subtract 1 from `f` before the fit.)

Comment: Your example data has not enough time points for a reasonable non-linear model fit.

Comment: some subjects have dozens observations, but some only have 2 observations. I can omit those subjects with less than, say, 3 observations? how to determine if the time points is enough is still a problem